# Serialize JsonNode to a very specific JSON format in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I have `JsonNode` result that I want to print out. So far, I am using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
File outputFile = new File(
    getCurOutputDir(), String.format("out.json", getClass().getSimpleName())
);
mapper.writeValue(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), resultNode);
```

which outputs something like:

```
{
  "A" : [ {
    "Ai" : {
      "Ai1" : 42,
      "Ai2" : 55
    }
  } ],
    "B" : [ 86 ]
}
```

but I need it to be in this specific format:

```
{
  "A" : [ 
    {
      "Ai" : {
        "Ai1" : 42,
        "Ai2" : 55
      }
    } 
  ],
    "B" : [
      86 
    ]
}
```

For context, I am transitioning from `JSONObject` to Jackson, so the second output is the one that is outputted by `JSONObject.serialize()`.

Also, is there a name for each of the format presented above? It seems like it abides by different standards.

Comment: I'm not sure, I understand the purpose of getClass().getSimpleName()) in String.format("out.json", getClass().getSimpleName()), the result will still be out.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize how Jackson will indent the output. There are different ways to achieve it, according to the Jackson version you are using.

### Jackson 2.5 and newer versions

Do the following:

```java
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
Indenter indenter = new DefaultIndenter();
printer.indentObjectsWith(indenter); // Indent JSON objects
printer.indentArraysWith(indenter);  // Indent JSON arrays

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writer(printer).writeValue(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), node);
```

By default, 2 spaces will be used. For a different number of spaces, use the [`DefaultIndenter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter.html) constructor that receives a string to indent levels and the line separator:

```java
Indenter indenter = new DefaultIndenter("      ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF);
```

### Jackson 2.4 and older versions

Do the following:

```java
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
Indenter indenter = new Lf2SpacesIndenter();
printer.indentObjectsWith(indenter); // Indent JSON objects
printer.indentArraysWith(indenter);  // Indent JSON arrays

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writer(printer).writeValue(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), node);
```

The [`Lf2SpacesIndenter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.Lf2SpacesIndenter.html) is limited to 2 spaces and you cannot change it.

If you need a different number of spaces, you need to write your custom implementation. Here's one that uses the same code as the [`DefaultIndenter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter.html) introduced in Jackson 2.5:

```
/**
 * Default linefeed-based indenter.
 */
public class CustomSpaceIndenter extends DefaultPrettyPrinter.NopIndenter {

    public final static String SYS_LF;
    static {
        String lf;
        try {
            lf = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            lf = "\n"; // fallback when security manager denies access
        }
        SYS_LF = lf;
    }

    public static final CustomSpaceIndenter SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE = 
            new CustomSpaceIndenter("  ", SYS_LF);

    /**
     * We expect to rarely get indentation deeper than this number of levels,
     * and try not to pre-generate more indentations than needed.
     */
    private final static int INDENT_LEVELS = 16;
    private final char[] indents;
    private final int charsPerLevel;
    private final String eol;

    /**
     * Indent with two spaces and the system's default line feed
     */
    public CustomSpaceIndenter() {
        this("  ", SYS_LF);
    }

    /**
     * Create an indenter which uses the <code>indent</code> string to indent one level
     *  and the <code>eol</code> string to separate lines.
     */
    public CustomSpaceIndenter(String indent, String eol)  {
        charsPerLevel = indent.length();
        indents = new char[indent.length() * INDENT_LEVELS];
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<INDENT_LEVELS; i++) {
            indent.getChars(0, indent.length(), indents, offset);
            offset += indent.length();
        }
        this.eol = eol;
    }

    public CustomSpaceIndenter withLinefeed(String lf) {
        if (lf.equals(eol)) {
            return this;
        }
        return new CustomSpaceIndenter(getIndent(), lf);
    }

    public CustomSpaceIndenter withIndent(String indent) {
        if (indent.equals(getIndent())) {
            return this;
        }
        return new CustomSpaceIndenter(indent, eol);
    }

    public String getEol() {
        return eol;
    }

    public String getIndent() {
        return new String(indents, 0, charsPerLevel);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInline() { 
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeIndentation(JsonGenerator jg, int level) throws IOException {
        jg.writeRaw(eol);
        if (level > 0) { // should we err on negative values (as there's some flaw?)
            level *= charsPerLevel;
            while (level > indents.length) { // unlike to happen but just in case
                jg.writeRaw(indents, 0, indents.length); 
                level -= indents.length;
            }
            jg.writeRaw(indents, 0, level);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used as following:

```java
Indenter indenter = new CustomSpaceIndenter("      ", CustomSpaceIndenter.SYS_LF);
```

Comment: Hey, sorry about the late change, but it seems like I am using Jackson 2.4.4, and `DefaultIndenter` was introduced in 2.5. Is there a way around it without using `DefaultIndenter`?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP For Jackson 2.4.4, use `new DefaultPrettyPrinter.Lf2SpacesIndenter()` instead of `new DefaultIndenter("  ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF)`. This approach was already mentioned in [Jaythaking's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476153/1426227). However, you'll only have the desired result if you customize the indent for arrays (`printer.indentArraysWith(indenter)`).

Comment: Sorry again about late request, but is 2 spaces fixed? I was wondering if we could generate 3/6/9/12/... spaces indent.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP Yes, the `Lf2SpacesIndenter` is 2 spaces fixed. Check my updated answer for an approach that allows you to define the number of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a custom `DefaultPrettyPrinter` using this:

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter pp = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
pp.indentObjectsWith(new Lf2SpacesIndenter());
pp.indentArraysWith(new Lf2SpacesIndenter("\r\n"));
mapper.writer(pp).writeValue(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), resultNode);
```

Take a look at the method provided by `DefaultPrettyPrinter` [HERE](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.html#DefaultPrettyPrinter())

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the same output as the first JSON? That is `[ {` are still in the same line

Comment: That's not the way to go in the most recent versions of Jackson. `Lf2SpacesIndenter` is deprecated since Jackson 2.5 and I think it was removed in Jackson 2.7.

Comment: It won't produce the desired output. You must indent the arrays as well. Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476346/1426227).

Comment: I gave the tool and the way to do. One shouldn't always expect copy-paste ready solutions. Good for you if you can improve my answer to make it your own...

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP to make your array indent on different line, you have to specify a carryage String as attribute to Lf2SpacesIndenter... (See my updated answer)

Comment: Hello, is it possible to have three spaces indent instead of two? Sorry about late update.