# Jackson - Using custom PrettyPrinter with custom JsonSerializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I am using Jackson v2.8.2 to serialise JSON to a file.

I have created a custom serializer and implemented the `serialize` method to customise the JSON output as required.

I am invoking the serializer as follows:

```
// myClass is the object I want to serialize

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(MyClass.class, new MySerializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.registerModule(module);

try 
{
    mapper.writeValue(new File("json.txt"), myClass);
}

catch (JsonProcessingException e) 
{
    ...
}
```

The JSON file is created and the content looks good.

The file is formatted according to the `DefaultPrettyPrinter` but I want to use my own custom `PrettyPrinter`, which I have already implemented.

How do I do that?

I've tried the following:

```
MyPrettyPrinter myPrettyPrinter = new MyPrettyPrinter();
mapper.writer(myPrettyPrinter);
mapper.writeValue(new File("json.txt"), myClass);
```

but that isn't invoking my custom printer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that the invocation of writer returns a new instance of the ObjectWriter. In fact, ObjectMapper has a lot of factory methods that construct new objects for you to work with.

The sourcecode from ObjectMapper:

```
/**
     * Factory method for constructing {@link ObjectWriter} that will
     * serialize objects using specified pretty printer for indentation
     * (or if null, no pretty printer)
     */
    public ObjectWriter writer(PrettyPrinter pp) {
        if (pp == null) { // need to use a marker to indicate explicit disabling of pp
            pp = ObjectWriter.NULL_PRETTY_PRINTER;
        }
        return _newWriter(getSerializationConfig(), /*root type*/ null, pp);
    }
```

So for you that means, that you should change your code to:

```
MyPrettyPrinter myPrettyPrinter = new MyPrettyPrinter();
ObjectWriter myWriter = mapper.writer(myPrettyPrinter);
myWriter.writeValue(new File("json.txt"), myClass);
```

Note the assignment to myWriter so that you are using the correct writer when calling `writeValue`

Here is an example using the ObjectMapper and the default pretty printer:

```
public class OMTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // test string
        String json = "  {\"a\" : \"b\", \"c\" : \"d\" } ";
        // mapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json tree
        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);
        // the objectWriter assigned with a pretty printer
        ObjectWriter myWriter = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
        // print without pretty printer (using mapper)
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(tree));
        System.out.println();
        // print with writer (using the pretty printer) 
        System.out.println(myWriter.writeValueAsString(tree));
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
{"a":"b","c":"d"}

{
  "a" : "b",
  "c" : "d"
}
```

Where the first line uses the mapper, while the second print uses the writer.

Cheers,

Artur

Comment: If I change the code as you suggest it doesn't compile - `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ObjectWriter to ObjectMapper`.

Comment: @ksl you are right. I apologise, i updated my answer. You'll have to assign the writer to a variable and use that one

Comment: Thanks, that works. Note also that `mapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(new MyPrettyPrinter())` also works. I stumbled upon that here - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/689.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, depending on what you want to achieve, you could use the [`DefaultPrettyPrinter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.html) and just customize the [`Indenter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter.Indenter.html), as following:

```java
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
Indenter indenter = new CustomSpaceIndenter();
printer.indentObjectsWith(indenter); // Indent JSON objects
printer.indentArraysWith(indenter);  // Indent JSON arrays
```

There's a related question about it: [Serialize JsonNode to a very specific JSON format in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39475967/1426227)